# PHP Regular expressions problem

Tags: php, html, regex

I have this simple phrase that I need the last url value of.

```
<h4>Location</h4><a href="link">NOT NEEEDED</a> > <a href="link">NOT NEEDED</a> > <a href="link">NEED</a><br />
```

The HTML is constant is regards to the layout, the only thing that will change is the number of links.

I was wondering if anybody has any thoughts on always **grabbing the last** link's value, even if there is only one link.

Comment: Do the links always follow the <h4> tag and precede the <br /> tag?  If so you could use preg_match but you will need to look for the h4 as there may be more links on the page that cause the below answers to not quite work right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try this:

```
preg_match_all("/href=\"([^\"]+)\"/",$html,$m);
$last = array_pop($m[1]);
```

Answer (score 3):

It has been regurgitated hundreds of times, the ol' *dangers of using regex to parse HTML*.

Whilst I'm sure a regex would suffice for this subset of HTML, I still believe you're better off using...

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;

$dom->loadHTML($html);

$anchors = $dom->getElementsByTagName('a');

$lastHref = $anchors->item($anchors->length - 1)->getAttribute('href');
```

[CodePad](http://codepad.viper-7.com/2GTPci).

Much more robust IMO.

Comment: +1, but first you need to select the parent-element, which holds the breadcrumb navigation (e.g. `$breadcrumb = $dom->getElementByID('breadcrumb');`) and then use that element to get the child's via tag-name (`$anchors = $breadcrumb->getElementsByTagName('a');`).

Comment: @eeela: It's not neccesary. `getElementsByTagName()` will get all descendent elements of the node it was called on.

Comment: It's necessary if the input is the whole HTML-document, otherwise you will get all links from all over the page.

Comment: @eeela: For the portion the OP quoted, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with alex; you generally don't want to use regular expressions to parse markup. If you have any issues with malformed markup while using his example, try using the tidy extension to clean it up first: http://php.net/manual/en/tidy.examples.basic.php